# Which php.ini file do I have to edit on Mountain Lion?

Tags: macos, apache, php

I recently upgraded to Mountain Lion and reconfigured my apache2 (`https.conf`) file in the terminal to load PHP and start automatically.

My `localhost/~username/phpinfo.php` page comes up to show my PHP configuration (`php.ini`).  I see that `upload_files` is set to ON and the `max_size_upload` is set to 20MB.  However, the `upload_tmp_dir` isn't set (it says NO VALUE).  I assume the default tmp directory is "/tmp".

When I do

```
$ cd /etc/
$ sudo nano php.ini.default
```

goto the `upload_tmp_dir` and I remove the `;` in front of it and enter the value `/tmp` (save and exit).

I still see NO VALUE for the `upload_tmp_dir` when I load my `phpinfo.php`.  I just wonder if I'm doing something wrong.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you restart apache after changing the setting? I.E. Turn off/on web sharing (i think?) in sys prefs?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`/etc/php.ini.default` serves only as a reference and is not read out by PHP at all. The built-in PHP installation will look for the file `/etc/php.ini` instead. This file is not present by default, but you can copy `/etc/php.ini.default` to `/etc/php.ini` and make your modifications in there. You could also just create an empty file and only add any directives you want to change from the default.

Make sure you copy or create the file as root, so in Terminal you could do:

`sudo cp /etc/php.ini.default /etc/php.ini`

After modifying the php.ini, also make sure you restart Apache for the settings to take effect.

It is good practice to not modify `/etc/php.ini.default` directly, so you can use it as a reference if anything goes wrong with your `/etc/php.ini`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple installations of php, then you should use the php command to find the ini files.

```
$ /usr/local/opt/php56/bin/php --ini
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /usr/local/etc/php/5.6
Loaded Configuration File:         /usr/local/etc/php/5.6/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /usr/local/etc/php/5.6/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)
```